# XA Transaction Issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, distributed-transactions, xa, atomikos

We have a specific requirement to consume one inbound messages from IBM MQ (source), generate around 3k outbound messages and publish all of them one by one to a destination IBM MQ - All this in 1 transaction - Transaction time out duration is 5 mins.
We are using Atomikos XA for our spring boot application to implement this requirement but getting a major issue when the transaction is timing out after 5 mins and within this time not all outbound messages were published to destination IBM MQ. I can see that 1k messages got published to the destination queue and the inbound message was rolled back to the source queue.
As we are using XA, none of outbound messages should have got published is my expectation but that's not the case - Is this not how XA works? Am i missing something here? Please clarify

Comment: Is it possible to consume the outbound messages on the other side? Either they have in fact been rolled back and only seem published or (more likely) you have an error in your configuration. It is possible to enlist the outbound messages in the same XA transaction as the inbound, but setting things up can be tricky.

Comment: when i shut down my spring boot application, these outbound messages should have got rolled back (removed) from MQ but that's not the case - I have inbound and outbound wrapped up in 1 XA transaction and so am curious to know if XA should have rolled back (removed) the messages after timeout as the application was not able to publish all the outbound messages within the specified time

Comment: If things are configured correctly the messages should not be there before the application commits. If it times out there is presumably no commit, so there should be no messages. Note that a message can be visible but not readable in some products (not sure about MQ), so if you want to be sure try to consume it. If that works before you have committed then you have an error in your code or configuration.